# How do I pull out a specific component of the output of a function in R?

Tags: r

I am using the t.test() function. The output has a component "p.value" which I would like direct access to. For example, I would like to be able to append this p.value to a list.

Your advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `t.test` is just a list:

```
t.test(runif(10))$p.value
# [1] 0.0001406559
```

Also, here are the other things you can pull out:

```
names(t.test(runif(10)))
# [1] "statistic"   "parameter"   "p.value"     "conf.int"    "estimate"    "null.value" 
# [7] "alternative" "method"      "data.name"
```